# Put Windows 8 recovery inside laptop hard drive, Sony Vaio T13

Tags: windows-8

A month ago or so I made a copy of the recovery partition using the Windows option to create recovery unit, and when it finished I chose the option to delete recovery partition from the hard drive.

A new 25 GB hard drive appeared, everything was fine.

Now I would like to sell this laptop but I don't know how to put the recovery partition back in its place or if it's even possible.

Comment: If you restore from the recovery disk you made, does it put it back?

Comment: I tried to copy the recovery disk to the recovery partition using cp -r in linux and marking the partition as hidden and recovery with gparted. I also tried with dd but with no luck cause the recovery unit made by windows is larger (30gb) than the original altough only 22gb are used. No luck in bootig from it afterwards

Comment: If you didn't create an image of the entire disk and its partitions unless you delete all the partitions and create the partitions of the correct size there isn't much you can do

Comment: Hi, I didn't change the partition layout, the size of partitions it's factory default. The recovery partition was 25GB, but the recovery unit that Windows creates is of 30GB of which only 22 are used.

Comment: @techie007, sorry I didn't read it correctly before, the answer is no, from the recovery disk I can get the laptop back to default but I does not recreate the recovery partition

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create bootable recovery partition to restore windows 7 partition as it is now](http://superuser.com/questions/688358/how-to-create-bootable-recovery-partition-to-restore-windows-7-partition-as-it-i)

Comment: @techie007 Hi, I readed the link you posted, it explains how to create a new recovery partition, but I already have a recovery, what I look for is a way to put back the recovery partition inside the laptop drive...

Answer (score -1):

I used Acronis DiskDirector to do just this... however it's not free.

Comment: Hi, so it's possible... Does the program have specific options for this matter? Could you explain how did you did it please? If I can do it with it maybe it's worth the price. Thanks

Comment: well I have looked at the program you mention, it's not compatible with gpt partition layouts :(